# How do I fetch api for my first weather app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch an api from this website (https://openweathermap.org/) but for some reason I'm still confused on how to get the api key. Right now I'm trying to "reverse code" a function component into a class based component weather app. If it's not too much trouble I also want help on how I can get my search bar to fetch api when a city or state is entered. These are my only issues.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

const api = {
    key: "97069e2620a78cbdae3b830af4dd7929",
    base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.0/" 
  }

class Weather extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            searchBar:"",
            temp:"",
            weather:"",
            location:"",
            

        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }


    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]: value})
    }

    
    componentDidMount(event) {
        fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                const {cloud} = response.data
                this.setState({search: cloud})
            })
    }


    render() {
        let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        let date = String(new window.Date());
        date = date.slice(0,15)


        return(
            <div className="App">
                <main>
                    <div className="search-box">
                        <input type="text"
                        name="search-bar" 
                        className="search-bar"
                        placeholder="Search"
                        onKeyPress={""}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.searchBar}/> 
                    </div>

                    
                    <div className="location-box">
                        <div className="location">New York City</div>
                        <div className="date">{date}</div>
                        <div className="weather-box">
                        <div className="temp">15°c</div>
                        <div className="weather">Snowy</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Weather
```

Comment: your fetch url has to pass the api key according to their docs. At the moment, you are never sending it

Comment: Also, don't ever expose private api keys in public posts or git commits. They can be abused by others.

Comment: I didn't know thank you very much for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

https://openweathermap.org/appid

Copied directly from their docs:

Example on how to make an API call using your API key
API call

[http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid={API](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=%7BAPI) key}
Parameters
appid   required    Your unique API key (you can always find it on your account page under the "API key" tab)
Example of API call

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid={API key}

The fix for your code assuming the same location id:

```
fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=${api.key}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            const {cloud} = response.data
            this.setState({search: cloud})
        })
```

Comment: Also I have a quick question, how can I convert this in my class based component: onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} Also I was able to fetch my api by using await. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here under Controlled Components: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html